# I cannot uninstall Genymotion

Tags: uninstall, genymotion, android-emulator

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; I'm new to Linux. I've installed Genymotion a long time ago together with Virtual Box, in order to run an Android emulation on my desktop.

Now, I decided to remove them. I successfully uninstalled Virtual Box, but Genymotion is still there and there is no way i can remove it.

It is stored in `/home/sandip/downloads/genymotion`

None of the commands below work. The terminal says the directory or package can't be find or that the command is invalid.

```
sudo rm -r ~/genymotion
sudo apt-get --purge remove genymotion
sudo rm -fr ~/.Genymobile ~/.config/Genymotion.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's almost as if you answered your own question.

You didn't seem to have installed it via the package manager so using `apt-get` won't get you far. That's why it can't find the package since it doesn't know anything of it.

The path `~/genymotion` doesn't exist since you said it is stored in `/home/sandip/downloads/genymotion`.

So try using the installer since it has an `uninstall` option

```
sudo /path/to/genymotion-x.x.x_x64.bin --uninstall
```

Comment: It says no such directory....